# ejabberd pubsub related commands

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have ejabberd 19.02 installed on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I would like to find out if an admin can issue pub/sub related commands such as node creation, subscribing a jid to a node, sending a message to a node, etc., from either `ejabberdctl` or ejabberd Rest API.

I have searched everywhere and don't see any reference to it. In my ejabberd.yml file, I see the pubsub related options like below.

```
mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - "flat"
      - "pep"
    force_node_config:
      ## Change from "whitelist" to "open" to enable OMEMO support
      ## See https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/2425
      "eu.siacs.conversations.axolotl.*":
        access_model: whitelist
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      "storage:bookmarks":
        access_model: whitelist
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_pubsub does not provide any command. You can try to use the send_stanza command to send the corresponding XMPP packets...